# Changing constant pointer's address

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand one thing.

I know I can't change constant pointer's value, but I can change its address, if I initialize a pointer the following way:

```
int foo = 3;
const int *ptr = &foo;
*ptr = 6; // throws an error
int bar = 0;
ptr = &bar; // foo == 0
```

Now, let's say I declare (/define, I never remember which one) a function:

```
void change(const int arr[], int size);

int main() {
   int foo[2] = {};
   change(foo, 2);
   std::cout << foo[0];
}

void change(const int arr[], int size) {
   // arr[0] = 5 - throws an error
   int bar = 5;
   arr = &bar;
}
```

The last line in the code above doesn't throw any errors. However, when the function is over and I display the first element, it shows 0 - so nothing has changed.

Why is that so?

In both situations I have constant pointers, and I try to change its address. In the first example it works. In the second one it doesn't.

---

I also have another question. I've been told that if I want to pass two-pointers type to the function, const keyword won't work as expected. Is that true? And if so, then what's the reason?

Comment: Downvoting for learning new programming language - I love this website :P

Comment: @userXXX Downvoting for not showing enough research effort. I love lazy users :P

Comment: @user2252786 You've got comprehensive answers here from four of the top people on the website.

Comment: That's why I said I love this website :P

Comment: I appreciate this question. I'm glad people are brave enough to ask these "simple" questions even though they get accused of "screwing" up something "a lot".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're screwing up the terminology a lot, so I'm going to start there because I think it is a major cause of your confusion. Consider:

```
int x;
int* p = &x;
```

`x` is an `int` and `p` is a "pointer to `int`". To *modify the value of `p`* means to change `p` itself to point somewhere else. A pointers value is the address it holds. This pointer `p` holds an address of an `int` object. To change the pointer's value doesn't mean to change the `int` object. For example, `p = 0;` would be modifying `p`'s value.

In addition to that, the *address of `p`* is not the address it holds. The address of `p` would be what you get if you did `&p` and would be of type "pointer to pointer to `int`". That is, the address of `p` is where you would find the pointer `p` in memory. Since an object doesn't move around in memory, there's no such thing as "changing its address".

So now that's out of the way, let's understand what a constant pointer is. `const int*` is *not* a constant pointer. It's a pointer to a constant object. The object it points to is constant, not the pointer itself. A constant pointer type would look more like `int* const`. Here the `const` applies to the pointer, so it is of type "`const` pointer to `int`".

Okay, now I'll quickly give you an easy way to remember the difference between declaration and definition. If you bought a dictionary and all it had was a list of words in it, would you really call it a dictionary? No, a dictionary is supposed to filled with definitions of words. It should tell you what those words mean. The dictionary with no definition is only declaring that such words exist in the given language. So a declaration says that something exists, and a definition gives the meaning of it. In your case:

```
// Declaration
void change(const int arr[], int size);

// Definition
void change(const int arr[], int size) {
   // arr[0] = 5 - throws an error
   int bar = 5;
   arr = &bar;
}
```

Now to explain the issue here. There's no such thing as an array argument type. Any array type argument is converted to a pointer. So the declaration of `change` is actually identical to:

```
void change(const int arr*, int size);
```

when you do `arr = &bar;` you are simply assigning the address of `bar` to the pointer `arr`. That has no effect on the array elements that `arr` is pointing to. Why should it? You are simply changing where `arr` points to, not the objects it points at. And in fact you can't change the objects it points at because they are `const` `int`s.

Comment: The keyword `const` doesn't actually mean the same thing as "constant" (though it's obviously derived from the word). `const` means "read-only". A *constant* expression is one that can be evaluated at compile time. For example: `const int r = rand();` is legal; the value of `r` is obviously not constant, but it's read-only.

Comment: Wow, I finally understood a lot of difficult-for-me things in c++, thanks a lot!

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, that's a very good point. It's pretty common to talk about `const` variables as being "constant variables" though. I'll edit my question to remove ambiguity though.

Comment: I've found a really good way to remember this is to start from the variable name and move away. So `const int *p` is: `p` is a `*` to `int` `const`. And `int *const p;` is: `p` is a `const` `*` to `int`. This is a simple form of the [right-left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html)

Answer (score 7):

> I know I can't change constant pointer's value, but I can change its address

Nah. You can't change the address of anything. Did you mean that you can't change the object it points to, but you can change the pointer itself? Because that's what is the truth - **in the case of a pointer-to-const type.** However, if you have a const pointer to a non-const object, then you can't change the pointer, you can only change whatever it points to.

Addendum (edit): a handy rule of thumb is that `const` applies to what stands on its left side, except when nothing stands on its left side, because then it applies to the type that is on its right side. Examples:

```
const int *ptr;
int const *ptr; // these two are equivalent: non-const pointer to const int

int *const ptr; // const pointer to non-const int

int const *const ptr; // const pointer to const int
const int *const ptr; // same as above
```

> However, when the function is over and I display the first element, it shows 0 - so nothing has changed.

Scope. `arr` is a function argument - so it's local to the function. Whatever you do with it, it won't be effective outside of the function. To achieve what you want, declare it as a reference:

```
void change(const int *&arr, int size)
```

> I've been told that if I want to pass two-pointers type to the function, const keyword won't work as expected. Is that true?

This depends on what your expectations are. If you read the standard attentively and have proper expectations, then it will indeed work as expected. Examples:

```
const int **ptr; // pointer to pointer to const int
int const **ptr; // same as above
const int *const *ptr; // pointer to const pointer to const int
```

etc. You can generate more of these funky declarations using [CDecl](http://cdecl.org)

Comment: "Declare foo as pointer to pointer to function (void) returning pointer to pointer to pointer to array 3 of int" - no wonder pointers are a milestone in c++ for most newbies :D

Comment: @user2252786 Well... one shall not start with pointers-to-member-functions-that-return-pointers-to-arrays, so to say.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is using the proper terms, which actually helps in understanding:

```
const int *ptr = &foo;
```

That is a *pointer to a constant integer*, not a *constant pointer to an integer*. You cannot change the object pointed, but you can change the pointer to refer to a different object.

```
void change(const int arr[], int size);
```

That signature is processed by the compiler as `void change( const int *arr, int size )`, and I'd recommend that you type it as that, as it will reduce confusions. Where the function is called, `change(foo,2)`, the compiler will transform the argument `foo` (type is `int[2]`) to `&foo[0]` which has type `const int*` (both transformations are commonly called *decay* of the array to a pointer).

Now as in the first block of code, you cannot change the pointed memory, but you can change the pointer to refer to a different object.

Additionally, in C++ the default mode is pass-by-value. The pointer `arr` inside `change` is a *copy* of the value `&foo[0]`. Inside the function you are changing that copy, but that will not affect anything outside of the function context.

Answer (score 0):

`const int *` is doing what it's supposed to do, what's confusing you is its purpose.

Think of it as a pointer to a readonly int. You can point to any int you want, but it's going to be readonly no matter what.

You might use this to loop through an array of type `const int`, for example.